# "Correct" way to get data, wait and then navigate (C#, Xamarin, MAUI)

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, maui

i am developing an app using .NET MAUI in which i have a "loader" page that gets navigated after successful login and after each new start of the app once logged in.

Currently using Shiny framework (it includes PRISM, ReactiveUI and some other goodies) so most of the code is inside OnNavigatedTo() method

What i am trying to do is, after Navigate to this loader page, i need to retrieve some data from 3 different endpoints (using Refit to do it) and after each one is finished, i update some text in the mainthread ("Loading xxxxx...").. to inform the user something is running...

After all 3 calls are completed, then i want to Navigate to my main page..

Everything seems to work, but **sometimes (when the test server is idle and it takes a little bit longer), i navigate to mainpage BEFORE the calls are completed, so i get nothing** because i need the data to achieve some stuff.

So my question is... what would be the "correct" way to perform this?

Before i used to use ContinueWith in my GetCatalogs() call, but the issue happened anyways:

`await GetCatalogs().ContinueWith(() => //Perform Navigation Code);`

So now i have this

```
      public override void OnNavigatedTo(INavigationParameters parameters)
        {
            IsBusy = true;
          

            MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => {
                await GetCatalogs();
                await Navigation.NavigateAsync("app:///NavigationPage/MainPage");
            });

        }

     private async Task GetCatalogs()
        {
            try
            {
                MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    LoadingText = "Loading Vendors...";
                });
           
                AppSingleton.ApbCatalog = await AppSingleton.ApiService.GetApbCatalog();
                
                MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    LoadingText = "Loading Produce Catalog...";
                });
            
                AppSingleton.ProduceCatalog = await AppSingleton.ApiService.GetProduceCatalog();

                MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    LoadingText = "Loading Generic Catalog...";
                });
               
                AppSingleton.GenericCatalog  = await AppSingleton.ApiService.GetGenericCatalog();
       
            }
            catch(Exception ex) {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code #1**

`BeginInvokeOnMainThread` is "fire and forget": there is no guarantee whether the code inside is run before or after your later code.

You want to "await" the code, using `await MainThread.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync`:

```cs
private async Task GetCatalogs()
{
    try
    {
        await MainThread.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync(() =>
        {
            LoadingText = "Loading Vendors...";
        });
   
        AppSingleton.ApbCatalog = await AppSingleton.ApiService.GetApbCatalog();
        
        await MainThread.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync(() =>
        {
            LoadingText = "Loading Produce Catalog...";
        });
    
        ...       
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

---

**Code #2**

HOWEVER, currently you are already on MainThread from your caller; you don't need additional MainThread methods, unless you are on a background thread. Try it without those:

```cs
private async Task GetCatalogs()
{
    try
    {
        LoadingText = "Loading Vendors...";
   
        AppSingleton.ApbCatalog = await AppSingleton.ApiService.GetApbCatalog();
        
        ...
```

---

**Code #3**

OTOH, maybe you didn't mean to be on MainThread for EVERYTHING in GetCatalogs. Perhaps what you wanted was to wrap the whole thing in Task.Run:

```cs
private async Task GetCatalogs()
{
    await Task.Run( async() =>
    {
        // Running on background thread.
        try
        {
            await MainThread.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync(() =>
            {   // Running on MainThread.
                LoadingText = "Loading Vendors...";
            });
       
            AppSingleton.ApbCatalog = await AppSingleton.ApiService.GetApbCatalog();
            
            await MainThread.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync(() =>
            {
                LoadingText = "Loading Produce Catalog...";
            });
        
            ...
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: MainThread.BeginInvoke... are used 3 times inside GetCatalogs() because otherwise, LoadingText doesnt update

Comment: Did one of the 3 work for you?